# How to capitalize the first letter of the first word of each line in a text file?

Tags: python

Here is my current code:

```
with open('Finna.txt') as bigtxt:
        for l in bigtxt:

            l = l.capitalize()
            print l
```

I tried simply calling the capitalize() method used above over the text file 'Finna.txt' listed below

```
Are there upcoming networking sessions?
Are there walk in hours during the summer?
are there walk in hours today?
Are there walk-in hours during finals?
are there work opportunities for freshmen in engineering career
```

expecting every line to be capitalized if it wasn't already but the only thing that was returned was

```
are there work opportunities for freshmen in engineering career
```

Which was uncapitalized. What am I doing wrong here? Apologies if this is a very elementary question, I am just getting started with Python. I tried searching for similar questions with my problem before posting.

Comment: There might be some control characters that you can't see or something.

Comment: `l.lstrip().capitalize()`?

Comment: I expect that you have invisible characters.  I build `Finna.txt` by pasting your data in to a text file, and the program runs just fine.

Comment: Some times it's beneficial to do `print([l])`, it's a dirty quick trick to see the raw string if there's any hidden control characters or something.

Comment: Keep in mind that str.capitalize() will return a string with the first letter capitalized and ALL others lower case.  If you have a proper name or place in your input text, it will be made lower case.

Comment: @Torxed why not just `print(repr(l))`?

Comment: Thank you all. I tried the print([1]) but it gave something like this ['Are there upcoming networking sessions?\rAre there walk in hours during the summer?\]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Faster to write `print([l])` - I'm a programmer, I'm lazy.. Sue me :)

Comment: Is there a way to work around invisible/control characters? If not, does that mean I have to find another method to capitalize the first letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the code and text that you have provided, the output seemed fine.

However, I'm guessing there might be some spaces or invisible characters that are present in your 'Finna.txt'. You could try something like this -

```
with open('finna.txt') as bigtxt:
        for l in bigtxt:

            l = l.strip().capitalize()
            print l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list-comprehension` and `lstrip()/rstrip()` each line then `capitalize()` and `join()` them for printing:

```
with open('test.txt.', 'r') as f:
    print '\n'.join([x.lstrip().rstrip().capitalize() for x in f])
```

output:

```
Are there upcoming networking sessions?
Are there walk in hours during the summer?
Are there walk in hours today?
Are there walk-in hours during finals?
Are there work opportunities for freshmen in engineering career
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code just replace the word with capitalized one

```
file = open('Finna.txt).read().splitlines()
for word in file:
    st = word.replace(word, word.capitalize())
    print(st)
```

The output will be:

```
Are there upcoming networking sessions?
Are there walk in hours during the summer?
Are there walk in hours today?
Are there walk-in hours during finals?
Are there work opportunities for freshmen in engineering career
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
f = open('Finna.txt')read().splitlines()

new_f = [i[0].upper()+i[1:] for i in f]
```

Output is a list of all lines that are now capitalized:

```
['Are there upcoming networking sessions?', 'Are there walk in hours during the summer?', 'Are there walk in hours today?', 'Are there walk-in hours during finals?', 'Are there work opportunities for freshmen in engineering career']
```